# Error during DataStax Opscenter startup, ImportError

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I have installed datastax opscenter 6.8 with reference to: [Datastax Docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.8/docs/installing/opscenter-from-rpm.html). However, the opscenter fails to start with the following error in startup.log file (/var/log/opscenter/).

```
06:42:34 [opscenterd] INFO: Loading OpsCenter...
06:42:34 [opscenterd] INFO: Updating system path
06:42:34 [opscenterd] INFO: Importing twisted logging
06:42:36 [opscenterd] INFO: Finished importing twisted logging
06:42:36 [opscenterd] INFO: Opscenterd starting up...
06:42:37 [opscenterd] ERROR: Critical error: Cannot start OpsCenter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/twistd", line 94, in <module>
    from twisted.scripts.twistd import run
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 13, in <module>
    from twisted.application import app
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/application/app.py", line 17, in <module>
    from twisted.application import service, reactors
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/application/service.py", line 24, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import defer
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 29, in <module>
    from twisted.python import lockfile, failure
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/python/lockfile.py", line 23, in <module>
    from os import kill
ImportError: cannot import name kill
```

I am aware that this issue can occur if /tmp is mounted with noexec. However, while checking it doesn't seem to be the case for me. My tmp mount config:

```
/tmp tmpfs tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,size=3961124k,nr_inodes=1048576
```

**My os**: Amazon Linux 2023. 
**Java Version**: openjdk version "1.8.0_402"

I don't see this in supported platforms in: [supported platforms](https://docs.datastax.com/en/home/docs/supported-platforms.html#_supported_platforms_for_opscenter_6_8_6_7_6_5_and_6_1). Is it due to unsupported os?

I have tested it in my vm with centos 7 and it works fine. Can anyone please help me debug this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you have [a valid & supported subscription](https://www.datastax.com/legal/datastax-opscenter-license-terms), you probably better of working with [*DataStax Support* portal](https://support.datastax.com). And, yes, if you're using an unsupported OS for the product, you're expected to run into problem such as what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, The issue was with the cpu architecture. I was using an instance with arm64 architecture. Switched to x86-64 and it worked. Took me long to debug. For those of you struggling, this might be the issue with you too.